# what is difference using of "地" and "得"

Tags: grammar

I have been learning Mandarin since 6 months ago, but i have problem with my title, could you guys make me clear about the difference between them?

if i have example of sentences like below is wrong:

```
很快地吃
```

but it i think if I make sentences like below right

```
她吃得很快
```

Because sometimes I was confused when I use "地" and "得" in above sentences, so please kindly help me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are three confusing words in Chinese: "的", "地", and "得".

For "的", it is usually used to describe the words following it. The structure is `adj. + 的 + noun`, for example, `勤劳的妈妈`.

For "地", it is usually used to describe the action following it. The structure is `adv. + 地 + verb`, for example, `积极地回答问题`. So `很快地吃` is correct. In a whole sentence, it might be `他正在很快地吃苹果`.

For "得", it is usually used to describe the action before itself. The structure is `verb + 得 + adv.`, for example, `回答得很好`, or `吃得很快`.

Answer (score 3):

We tend to put some adverbials in front of the verb but others after the verb. It depends on many factors.

It's hard to come up with a reasonable explanation why we say:

```
 (！indicates an imperative sentence, 。 a declarative sentence, and ， an incomplete sentence.)
快吃！
快点吃！
吃快点！
吃得快。
吃得很快。
快吃。
```

but

```
*快地吃！
*吃快！
*吃快。
*快地吃。
*吃得快！
```

Sometimes both are used:

```
他伤心地哭着，
他哭得很伤心。
```

Apparently, 地 is preferred when the verb is long or followed by something else.

```
?他开心地笑。
他开心地笑着，
他开心地大笑，
他笑得很开心。
他积极地回答问题。
*他回答问题得很积极。
他回答问题很积极。
他回答问题回答得很积极。
```

I think the word that comes after the verb is usually the focus or new information. If you omit the adverbs,

```
?他笑。
?他回答问题。
```

do not sound like complete sentences, which means the adverbs probably contain important information. That's why we tend to place them at the end of a sentence. On the other hand,

```
吃！
她吃完了。
他回答了问题。
```

are complete sentences, so

```
快吃！
她很快(地)吃完了。
他积极地回答了问题。
```

I think 了 is what makes all the difference--it means a new event has happened, which by itself contains significant information. We may first use 了 to notify a new event, then use 得 to add some details.

```
她吃完了，而且吃得很快。
他回答了问题，而且回答得很积极。
*她吃完了，而且很快地吃。
*她吃完了，而且很快地吃了。
*他回答了问题，而且很积极地回答。
*他回答了问题，而且很积极地回答了。
```

Not all adverbs/adjectives can appear in both positions, and not all of them need 得 or 地. For example, 快 itself is an adverb.

```
他快吃完了。 = He almost finished eating -> He is eating.
快吃。 -- 快 is more like “hurry up” or “come on”
他轻轻地说，
他说得很轻。
```